# change navigation up icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to change the "Navigation Up" icon with a drawable image(in eclipse) but all I can do now is change the logo(ic_launcher) instead. I uploaded an image [here is the link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md3vF.jpg) to circling the icon which I want to change. I tried to change it by using "@styles" but was unsuccessful. Thanks in advance for any help. Here is my code:

```html
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
  
  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
 }
 
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  
  switch(item.getItemId()){
   case android.R.id.home:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
  } 
  return true;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a custom theme for your activity in the manifest. The style should look like this,

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_custom_indicator</item>
</style>
```

finally set the style in the manifest,

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
```

You can also achieve this programatically,

Without support library

```
ActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);
```

With support library

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);
```